# Settimeout and setinterval memory usage

Tags: javascript, memory-management, memory-leaks

Does anybody know the memory usage and possible memory leaks with javascript functions `setTimeout` and `setInterval`?

Thank you.

Comment: that depends wholly on the js engine. what browser are you running this in?

Comment: This particular code snippet I am writing is targeted to IE7 and chrome.

Answer (score -1):

IE7 might (and probably does) have leaks. chrome is less likely but its always possible. js engines are complex. You might also be creating unknown numbers of timeouts and intervals that could eat up some memory.

Answer (score -1):

It's important to use [clearTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) on any timers that run and then stop.  Otherwise you're asking for memory leakage, especially if you're creating lots of timers by using loops.

If you clear them, it would take more than a handful of timers to cause any noticeable slowdowns.

Comment: -1 for retelling a myth. `clearTimeout` does nothing after the timeout has expired. It wouldn't make any sense to have such a requirement, unlike a lot of other garbage collection stuff an expired timeout is actually really easy for the VM to deal with as it is guaranteed never to be used for anything again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244309/is-there-memory-leak-issue-if-not-calling-cleartimout-after-calling-settimeout