# Is there memory leak issue if not calling clearTimout after calling setTimeout

Tags: javascript

After calling `setTimeout`, is there memory leak issue without calling `clearTimeout`?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you ask? Can you elaborate? Have you experienced memory leaks when you use setTimeout? Which browsers are you targeting?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No. clearTimeout only needs to be called if you want to stop a pending setTimeout from happening. After the setTimeout happens, the timer id is no longer valid but fortunately calling clearTimeout with an invalid timer id is harmless.

If you see memory leaks happening the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: what if the setTiemout is not called?

Comment: @jsbisht That does not make sense. The only reason a setTimeout is never called is if you never enter the event loop. For example if you have an infinite loop - then no setTimeout or network I/O or disk I/O will get called

Answer (score 7):

There are times when setTimeout can cause memory leaks... see the following article: [setTimeout memory leaks](https://web.archive.org/web/20120905111557/http://www.makemineatriple.com/2007/10/passing-parameters-to-a-function-called-with-settimeout)

Be warned that IEx has a garbage-collector subtlety, though; I think that if you reference a DOM variable in a Javascript closure, then the collection mechanism gets confused and it doesn't get trashed at the end of the request: eventually this becomes a memory leak. I think it's because DOM variables and internal JS variables get collected by two different collectors, and they don't communicate properly about what's no longer being used.

I think you can fix this by setting the variable to null:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    myFunction(parameter); 
    parameter = null
}, myTimeout);
```

This explicitly sets the garbage collection in motion.