# Does flash.utils.setTimeout() leak memory if clearTimeout() is not called?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

The [ActionScript 3 documentation for `flash.utils.setTimeout`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#setTimeout%28%29) claims:

> If you do not call the `clearTimeout()` function to cancel the `setTimeout()`call, the object containing the set timeout closure function will not be garbage collected.

This sounds ridiculous. There is no reason that it should hold a reference to a function/closure that it is never going to call again, and [the equivalent JavaScript functions do not leak memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4244309/1114).

Is this true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not true, at least in the current version of Flash.

I created a function which creates a large string, creates a closure referring to it, and then calls `setTimeout` with the closure.

```
public function tick():void {
    var data:String = "helloworld";
    for (var j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
        data += data;
    }

    var f = function() {
        var i = 0;
        if (data.length > 0) {
            i++;
        }
    };

    setTimeout(f, 0);
}
```

I ran this function very frequently, and used `System.totalMemory` (as well as the OS X Activity Monitor) to monitor Flash's memory usage.

```
function Main():void {
    setInterval(tick, 10);
    setInterval(display, 500);
}

public function display():void {
    trace("Memory usage: " + System.totalMemory + "B.");
}
```

The memory usage would go up briefly, but then would fall back down as the garbage collector jumped in. The average memory usage was stable over several minutes.

When I modified the code to keep an explicit reference to each closure<sup>1</sup>, memory usage went up to many gigabytes within a couple minutes. The documentation is outdated. Flash does not keep references to the closures passed to `setTimeout`. (At least on OS X; I assume it would be the same on Windows.)

<sub><sup>1</sup> I created an Array as a static class var and `push`ed each `f` onto it before calling `setTimeout`.</sub>