# Is it needed or a good practice to clear a timeout after it ran?

Tags: javascript, timeout, settimeout

I have to set a timeout several times after a certain event.

```
// initial value
var x = null;

// later
if (!x) {
    x = setTimeout(function() {
        // do some stuff
        clearTimeout(x);
        x = null; 
    }, 500);
}
```

Is it necessary or a good practice to call `clearTimeout(x);`? Or is the interal element gone by now?

The reason I'm asking this is: The script will run about a thousand times a day in a kiosk system. So it should not fill up the RAM over time or produce any other issues.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there memory leak issue if not calling clearTimout after calling setTimeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244309/is-there-memory-leak-issue-if-not-calling-cleartimout-after-calling-settimeout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a memory leak issue - [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244309/is-there-memory-leak-issue-if-not-calling-cleartimout-after-calling-settimeout) an SO post from a while back

Comment: Sorry about the confusion about the variable names. I've corrected the question. I shortened the name for the example and I simply forgot to change this one.

Comment: According to the answers of the linked question, calling `x = null;` should be enough, right?

Comment: if the timeout has fired then that should clear the associated resources.  I've found no reports to the contrary.  Suggest if you're concerned let it run continuously and check memory usage of the browser/PC and see if it's increasing.  I suspect the resources used by this command are extremely small however